# CONCAT function working on SQL Server database with compatibility level 100 (2008)

Tags: sql-server

I have a database running on a SQL Server 2017 instance (14.0), but on compatibility level for 2008 (10.0). And yet, when I run queries using CONCAT on against that database, they don't error out even though CONCAT was introduced in 2012. Is there something more I need to do so that this use case is handled, or is compatibility level not concerned with functions?

Comment: Why do you need to use 2008 compatibility mode? Some thing will work fine in compatibility mode and others don't. AFAIK, there isn't a set of rules like functions works and xxxx doesn't.

Comment: The goal of compatability mode is to let old code run on new servers, not to test code for old servers on new servers

Comment: @Andomar Ah, so compatibility level is to deal with deprecated functionality, is that it? That makes sense, I wrongly assumed it was essentially to make the server/DB operate as if it were running on whatever level you select. If you post as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Like I was saying, why would you want to intentionally make your system function like an old one? That would defeat the point of upgrading wouldn't it?

Comment: @SeanLange Sometimes we've had devs running a newer version of SQL server than what's running on servers. I had thought using compatibility level would ensure that if they use a feature not available on the old version of SQL server, it would fail. Obviously, we still catch the issues when testing on QA, but would save some time. That is, until we can get to using something like Vagrant or Docker to avoid this.

Comment: Ahh I gotcha. Just a misunderstanding of compatibility. It is a bit strange for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of compatability mode is to let old code run on new servers, not to test code for old servers on new servers.